# ImportError: cannot import name 'registry' - import pandas error(Anaconda Navigator) Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am a Windows user. I run Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator on a newly created environment. Pandas were working fine until yesterday gives me an error for import pandas.

ImportError: cannot import name 'registry'

The version shown on Anaconda Navigator - 0.24.1

The version shown on Jupyter Notebook - 1.1.5 (!pip show pandas)

Python version - 3.6.1(Anaconda3 64-bit)

I have tested clearing kernel and restarting the Anaconda app and my PC.
I did not do any changes to pandas.

Im working on a VDI(virtual environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try updating pandas using `pip3 install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: Hi. I tried this it gives me the following error. ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions'

Comment: @Dhakshika Your pip may be corrupted. Try updating pandas through `conda install pandas=1.5.0`